# How to decrease border width in any charts?

Tags: chart.js, ng2-charts

I am working with `ng2-charts` to draw line chart.  I want to reduce the thickness of line (decrease border width). I tried both `borderWidth` and `lineThickness` properties. But nothing seems to be working. Is there any other option or am I making any mistake ?

**Please have a look at the code**

[Demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stacked-bar-charts-4djsm4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misspelled `borderWidth` as `borederWidth` in your demo provided. Fixing that on your `chartData` gives you the desired result.

```js
...
chartData = [
  {
    ...
    borderWidth: 1, // <-- fix the spelling here
    ...
  },
  ...
];
...
```

Fixing this will give the following look:

[image: Fixed look]

Comment: oops.. My bad!! tysm

Comment: This isn't working for me. Is there a way to increase the size of line in ng2-line chart ? 
Any help would be appreciated.